# Does java mail do what this commercial email component does out of the box for free?

Tags: java, email, smtp, mime, pop3

I need to be able to pull emails into a web application, basically provide a full email interface like gmail (subject, from, attachments, embedded images, etc etc), pulling email via POP or IMAP.

the commercial product is here: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-email.asp

Do I need that product or will java mail do all this for me?

Comment: You could probably *use* Java mail to build a similar tool.

Comment: so its not as refined is what your saying....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a subset of what ChillKat Java Email does with Javamail.

Check out the Javamail project on Kenai,

http://kenai.com/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/show

in particular the IMAP package:

http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html

and the POP package:

http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html

You might also want to look at James and the way James uses Javamail for mail retrieval.

http://james.apache.org/

[Mailet](http://james.apache.org/mailet/) might provide some reusable components, but I've not used it so far.